# Temporarily disable nvidia driver on Debian Stretch

Tags: drivers, debian, nvidia-graphics-card, stretch

What is the correct procedure of temporarily disabling the nVidia driver in Debian Stretch (without removing any of the nVidia packages). I would like to test the Nouveau driver, and quickly switch back and forth to the nVidia driver.

(I could probably have this answered on IRC , but I prefer to ask here in case anyone else is interested in this question as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Add the nvidia driver

Comment `nouveau` driver then update `initramfs`

```
 update-initramfs -u
```

Answer (score 1):

On Debian 10 Buster I had to perform additional steps when compared to GAD3R's answer:

1. Blacklist the new modules: add

```
    blacklist nvidia
    blacklist nvidia_drm
    blacklist nvidia_modeset
```

to some file inside `/etc/modprobe.d/`.

2. Update the ramdisk: `# update-initramfs -u`
3. Disable the nvidia-persistenced service: `# systemctl disable nvidia-persistenced.service`

(It seems to be loading the driver regardless of the blacklist on my system.)